# Installing PHP on Fedora Core 5

Tags: php, fedora

Yes, I know FC5 is old but its what we have here.  I'm running

```
%./configure --with-mysql=/usr/include/mysql 
--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-zlib=/usr 
--with-magickwand=/usr/local/bin --enable-track-vars=yes --with-curl 
--with-xml=/usr/include/php/ext/xml 
--with-libxml-dir=/usr/include/php/ext/libxml --with-ldap=/usr  --with-gettext 
--with-gd  --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib --with-png-dir=/usr/lib --enable-ftp 
--with-openssl=/usr
...
%make
```

and I get:

```
%ext/gd/.libs/gd.o: In function `_php_image_bw_convert':/usr/local/src/php-5.2.5/ext/gd/gd.c:4854: undefined reference to `gdImageCreate'
```

:/usr/local/src/php-5.2.5/ext/gd/gd.c:4860: undefined reference to `gdImageColorAllocate'
.....

Why is this failing like this?  Is FC5 simply too old?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if gd-devel or libgd-devel is installed on the system.